# Assigning random rows from a dataframe into 2 other dataframes in R

Tags: r, random

I have a dataframe (a) as mentioned below:

```
   V1 V2
1   a  b
2   a  e
3   a  f
4   b  c
5   b  e
6   b  f
7   c  d
8   c  g
9   c  h
10  d  g
11  d  h
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h
```

Now what i want is to randomly assign rows from the above dataframe (a) to 2 other empty dataframes (b and c) such that none of the rows are repeated. That means neither b has any repeated rows nor c has any repeated row. Now apart from that even across b and c, none of the rows should be same i.e a row in b shouldn't be present in any rows of c and vice versa.

Once way is to sample 7 elements from (a) without replacement and assign to (b) and then assign remaining to the (c). But in this approach all elements would be assigned at the same time to (b) and then to (c) BUT what i want is to assign elements one by one. That is a random row to (b) then a random row to (c) then again a random row to (b) ... and so on till all rows in dataframe (a) are done.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @docendo-discimus. Let me explain clearly. Looking at the dataframe (a), I want to pick a random row then assign it to dataframe (b). Then i want to pick another random row from (a) and assign it to (c). I want to keep doing this till all the rows in (a) are done. This might not make sense as to why I am doing this one-by-one but this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling all of the row numbers and then partitioning the dataframe according to the parity of the row number indexes should achieve what you are after. This is the same as randomly partitioning the original dataframe row-by-row.

```
n <- nrow(df)
s <- sample.int(n, n)
odd.idxs <- seq_along(s) %% 2 != 0

s1 <- s[odd.idxs]
s2 <- s[-odd.idxs]

d1 <- df[s1, ]
d2 <- df[s2, ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. Could you please explain lines 2 and 3 of your code.

Comment: `sample.int` randomly samples all of the row indexes without replacement. Line 3 gets the odd indexes for the sample, ie., the indexes for every other sample.

Comment: Could you please use loops etc and assign the rows to the dataframes one by one using a loop please?
Your method assigns odd indexes and the relevant rows at once. I know using a loop won't be a efficient solution but say I want to use a loop and assign a random row from (a) to each of the dataframes (b and c) one by one till all the rows of (a) are done. Can you please mention the code for that type of solution? Thanks.

Comment: This is equivalent to doing that. This is the same as grabbing one random row and assigning to b, then getting another random row of those remaining and assigning it to c, then taking another random row and assigning it to b, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I got your point BUT I insist please let me know how to do this with a loop such that in each loop's iteration, a random row gets assigned to b and c.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Totally agreed. But I am not asking the solution to my homework. I searched tons of other SO posts relating to data.frame looping and when I couldn't find a similar post I had to create an account and ask the proper question myself. Thanks.