# Selecting random row from a data.frame and assigning it to one of the two other data.frames based on three conditions in R

Tags: r, random, dataframe

I have a data.frame (a) as mentioned below:

```
   V1 V2
1   a  b
2   a  e
3   a  f
4   b  c
5   b  e
6   b  f
7   c  d
8   c  g
9   c  h
10  d  g
11  d  h
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h
```

Lets assume each row represents an edge of a graph and the values of the rows are vertices.

What I want is to pick a random row (which is an edge) from data.frame (a) and assign it to data.frame (b) or data.frame (c) based on the three conditions below. Just to clarify that data.frame (b and c) are empty in the beginning. So the conditions are:

1. When a row(edge) is randomly picked from data.frame (a) and if neither vertex has been assigned, then assign the edge to the data.frame with least number of rows.

To clarify this condition:
Lets say I pick a random row(edge)#2 from data.frame (a) which has two vertices "a" and "e". So I should check if data.frame (b) and data.frame (c) have either "a" or "e" present in any of their rows. So if they have "a" or "e" present then this rule should not be implemented and next rule should be checked. If both data.frames do not have "a" or "e" present in any of the rows then nrow(number of rows) should be checked in both data.frames and the one with lower number of nrow() should be assigned that row. If both have same nrow() then any of the two data.frame could be assigned that row.

2. When a row(edge) is randomly picked from data.frame (a) and if one of the vertices of that row is present in any of the data.frames (b) or (c) then assign the row(edge) to that data.frame

If a random row is picked say for example #3 which has "a" and "f". Then data.frames b and c should be checked to see if any of the rows contain either "a" or "f". Suppose data.frame (b) does not contain either "a" or "f" but data.frame (c) contains "f". So the row should be assigned to data.frame (c). 
Now there is also a possibility that data.frame (b) contains "a" and data.frame(c) contains "f". In that case, all the instances of "a" in data.frame (b) and "f" in data.frame (c) should be counted. If "a" appears 3 times and "f" appears 4 times then the row should be assigned to (b) i.e The row then should be assigned to the data.frame which has lower number of instances of the vertex present in that data.frame.

3. When a row(edge) is randomly picked from data.frame (a) and if both the vertices of that row are present in a data.frame then assign the row to that data.frame

So to summarize, a random row should be picked from data.frame(a) and check for the above mentioned conditions and should be assigned to data.frame(b) or (c) after going through the conditions above. So all the rows of data.frame(a) have to be checked for the conditions.

Comment: Is this the same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29124060/633251)?  Just revised for clarity?

Comment: @Brayan Yes and No. This is a more detailed question regarding the same dataset. The previous question was just regarding random selection of rows through loop. This is about random selection and then comparing the selected row against few conditions (mentioned above) to see which condition matches. However if anyone answers this question, then my previous question would get answered too.

Comment: You are asking people to write a lot of code, which is not really in the spirit of SO.  Usually you should provide code you have written, but doesn't work quite the way you want.  You have articulated your question quite well.  Start writing code that takes care of each step.  Your first step is to create the original data frame and two empty data frames, then randomly select a row.  That would be a good starting point.  By the way, at what point would you judge the random selection of rows to be complete?

Comment: I did some initial steps of creating the data.frames and populating by loading the csv file. What I initially wanted to know was how to randomly select one row from data.frame(a) and then assign it to data.frame (b) then pick another random row from (a) and then assign it to (c) i.e picking random rows from (a)(but none of those rows should be selected again) and assigning to (b) and (c) one by one using a loop or something but no one gave me an answer which would do it one by one. Once all the rows of (a) are covered i.e selected and assigned to (b) or (c) then the process should be over.

Comment: I created a for loop and then sampled one random row from (a) and assigned it to (b) and then took a sample again and assigned it to (c) but the sample command would produce duplicate rows. Even without replacement, when sample is used again and again in a loop it gave me duplicates. I used False for sample command but that False holds true for the sample produced at a particular run. And since I am just using sample to get one row, false wouldn't be even necessary but the problem is when I run the same sample command multiple times, there is no guarantee the rows selected won't be duplicates.

Comment: So you want to use all the rows of `a` eventually, but in random order?

Comment: Yes Bryan and none of the rows of `a` should get repeated during selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.  You can't continually randomly select rows, as you discovered, as that leads to duplicates.  Instead, randomly assign the rows to a vector which gives the order they should be processed in.  If you don't think this is the right approach, you could also randomly select a row, then remove it from `a` and later randomly select from what remains.  If you still need `a`, remove the row from a copy of `a`.

```
set.seed(1)
dfa <- data.frame(V1 = sample(letters[1:9], replace = TRUE), V2 = sample(letters[1:9], replace = TRUE))

todo <- sample(1:nrow(dfa), nrow(dfa), replace = FALSE)

dfb <- dfa[todo[1],]
dfc <- dfa[todo[2],]
```

Now continue through 'todo' in order, applying your conditions
and using rbind to add rows to the dfb and dfc:

```
for (i in 3:length(todo)) {

    # apply your logic
    # if a row belongs in dfb, do
    dfb <- rbind(dfb, dfa[todo[i],])
    # etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know if you down voted the question to -2? Anyways thanks a ton for getting me started on the track.

Comment: No, I never down vote.  Though you had no code, you did write out pretty clearly what was wanted, which is helpful.  For me, drawing a picture usually helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does set.seed(1) do? I browsed several data.frames posts through SO and found coders using set.seed() while selecting random numbers or samples but in R the help for set.seed() doesn't clearly explain what it does or rather I wasn't able to make sense out of the explanation given in R for set.seed.

Comment: Yeah, it has a cryptic help page.  It just ensures that when different people run the 'random' code they get the same answer, which makes troubleshooting much easier, as everyone sees the same results.

Comment: FYI building objects within a `for` loop (reallocating memory) is bad practice in R, and should be avoided at all cost. See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) for some background.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I absolutely agree, but there was no clear way in this case to assign a size to the result, although I suppose all the new data frames could be made as large as the original and then `na.omit` applied to clean up.  Exercise left to the OP!

Comment: Hello Bryan thanks for your help above I was able to solve the code and posted the solution below. Can you please look at the new question I have on the link below and suggest any guidelines? Thanks
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408239)

Answer (score 0):

```html
aCopy<-read.table("isnodes.txt")
p1<-aCopy[-c(1:nrow(aCopy)),]
p2<-aCopy[-c(1:nrow(aCopy)),]
currentRowHistory<-aCopy[-c(1:nrow(aCopy)),]

for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
currentRow <- aCopy[sample(nrow(aCopy), 1), ]
currentRowHistory <- rbind(currentRow,currentRowHistory)
currentRowV1 <- as.character(currentRow$V1[1])
currentRowV2 <- as.character(currentRow$V2[1])
aCopy <- aCopy[!(aCopy$V1 == currentRowV1 & aCopy$V2 == currentRowV2),]

if(length(which(currentRowV1 == p1$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV1 == p1$V2))){
    if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V2))){
 p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1)
        result <- "case 1 assign it to p1"
    }
    else if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V2))){
 V1occurances <- length(which(p1$V1 == currentRowV1))+length(which(p1$V2==currentRowV1))
 V2occurances <- length(which(p2$V1 == currentRowV2))+length(which(p2$V2==currentRowV2))
 ifelse(V1occurances<V2occurances,p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1),p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2))
 result <- "case 2"
    }
    else {
 p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1)
        result <- "case 3 assign it to p1"
    }
} else if(length(which(currentRowV1 == p2$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV1 == p2$V2))){
    if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V2))){
 p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2)
        result <- "case 1 assign it to p2"
    }
    else if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V2))){
 V1occurancesInP2 <- length(which(p2$V1 == currentRowV1))+length(which(p2$V2==currentRowV1))
 V2occurancesInP1 <- length(which(p1$V1 == currentRowV2))+length(which(p1$V2==currentRowV2))
 ifelse(V1occurancesInP2<V2occurancesInP1,p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2),p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1))
        result <- "case 2"
    }
    else {
 p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2)
        result <- "case 3 assign it to p2"
    }
} else if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p1$V2))){
    p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1)
    result <- "Assign it to p1 case 3"
} else if(length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V1)) | length(which(currentRowV2 == p2$V2))){
 p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2)
    result <- "Assign it to p2 case 3"
} else {
    ifelse(nrow(p1)<nrow(p2),p1<-rbind(currentRow,p1), p2<-rbind(currentRow,p2))

}
}
```