# Assigning rows of data.frame to another data.frame in R based on frequency of element's occurance

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame **df**

```
> df
   V1 V2
1   a  b
2   a  e
3   a  f
4   b  c
5   b  e
6   b  f
7   c  d
8   c  g
9   c  h
10  d  g
11  d  h
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h
```

I found the frequency of each element's occurrence considering column **V1** and sorted the **Freq** column in ascending order

```
>dfFreq <- as.data.frame(table(df$V1))
  Var1 Freq
1    a    3
2    b    3
3    c    3
4    d    2
5    e    1
6    f    1
7    g    1

>dfFreqSorted <- dfFreq[order(dfFreq$Freq),]
  Var1 Freq
5    e    1
6    f    1
7    g    1
4    d    2
1    a    3
2    b    3
3    c    3
```

Now what i want to do is to create a new data.frame based on original data.frame such that each "**Var1**" item in "**dfFreqSorted**" is used according to it's Freq but once every time going from the top of "**dfFreqSorted**" to the bottom which would give the result below:

So consider the first Var1 item which is "**e**" so the first matching row of "**e**" in **V1** column of **df** is **(e,f)** which would be the first item in the new data.frame.
I figured that this can be done using:

```
>subset(df, V1==dfFreqSorted$Var[1])[1,]
   V1 V2
12  e  f
```

So if i used a for loop and looped through all the elements in the **Var1** column of **dfFreqSorted** and used the subset command above and rbind the returned result into another data.frame I would have something like below

```
   V1 V2
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h
10  d  g
1   a  b  
4   b  c
7   c  d
```

Now this result shows each **Var1** item once. I need the remaining rows as shown below such that after finishing first iteration of all the rows of **Var1** once, the loop should go again to the beginning and check the frequency of all **Var1** whose frequency is more than 1 now and find the next row from **df** for that element so the remaining rows that should be produced in the same data.frame as shown below:

```
11 d  h
2  a  e
5  b  e
8  c  g
3  a  f
6  b  f
9  c  h
```

As you can see above that all elements are considered in **Var1** whose frequency is 1 are used first then those whose frequency is greater than 1 (i.e 2) and are used once then in the next iteration those are used whose freq is greater than 2 (i.e 3) are used. Used such that corresponding unused row of that element is fetched from df.

So in short all the elements of df are arranged in anew data.frame such that elements are used in ascending order of their frequencies but used once first and then twice or thrice in every iteration based on what their frequency is.

I am not asking for the whole code just few guidelines of how i can achieve the objective. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to read the whole description.

Comment: Thanks. If it helps you visualize. Consider all the 14 values above as edges of a graph. So considering V1 as vertices, frequencies would be degrees of the vertives. So i need to take one edge from each vertex (in ascending order of degree) so the vertices according to degree ascending are e,f,g,d,a,b,c so i need to take an edge from each vertex then again go to begining i.e e and check if it has any more edge which it does not then go forward etc. When it comes to d since it has a degree of 2 so it has one more edge so use it then move to a,b,c then again go to begining. Did you got my point?

Comment: So in short i need to loop through all the vertices and pick an edge and assign to a data.frame such that i use one vertex every time. This looping would go on until the maximum frequency that an item has i.e maximum degree of a vertex.

Comment: Have you checked `library(igraph)`?  It may have some easy solutions (not sure though)

Comment: yes i checked it but the objective I want to achieve is quite different from what it offers. So i made it in a data.frame format and assumed someone could suggest a loop condition such that each vertex is used once and a data.frame is generated.

Comment: Looping is compulsory because this is 14 edges if there are 100s then i need to find the max frequency and loop until maximum frequency is reached. And use each item once according to the Var1 column of dfFreqSorted.

Comment: Does this boil down to sort `df` by the by the frequencies of the values in column 'V1`?

Comment: @AsadFerozAli  Please do post your solution if that solved the problem.

Comment: Ok @akrun i would do that now.

Answer (score 1):

Hello @akrun i am a beginner so the solution might be really a beginner level approach but it solved my problem perfectly fine.

```
> a<-read.table("isnodes.txt")
> a
   V1 V2
1   a  b
2   a  e
3   a  f
4   b  c
5   b  e
6   b  f
7   c  d
8   c  g
9   c  h
10  d  g
11  d  h
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h

> aF<-as.data.frame(table(a$V1))

> aF

  Var1 Freq
1    a    3
2    b    3
3    c    3
4    d    2
5    e    1
6    f    1
7    g    1

> aFsorted <- aF[order(aF$Freq),]

> aFsorted
  Var1 Freq
5    e    1
6    f    1
7    g    1
4    d    2
1    a    3
2    b    3
3    c    3

> sortedEdgeList <- a[-c(1:nrow(a)),]

> sortedEdgeList

[1] V1 V2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

> aFsorted <- cbind(aFsorted, Used=0)

> aFsorted
  Var1 Freq Used
5    e    1    0
6    f    1    0
7    g    1    0
4    d    2    0
1    a    3    0
2    b    3    0
3    c    3    0

> maxFreq <- max(aFsorted$Freq)

> maxFreq
[1] 3

> for(i in 1:maxFreq){
+     rows<-nrow(aFsorted)
+     for(j in 1:rows){
+         Var1Value<-aFsorted$Var[j]
+         Var1Edge<-a[match(aFsorted$Var1[j],a$V1),]
+         sortedEdgeList<-rbind(sortedEdgeList,Var1Edge)
+         a<-a[!(a$V1==Var1Edge$V1 & a$V2==Var1Edge$V2),]
+         aFsorted$Used[j]=aFsorted$Used[j]+1
+     }
+     if(aFsorted$Used==aFsorted$Freq){
+         aFsorted<-aFsorted[!(aFsorted$Used==aFsorted$Freq),]
+     } 
+ }

Warning messages:
1: In if (aFsorted$Used == aFsorted$Freq) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

2: In if (aFsorted$Used == aFsorted$Freq) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

3: In if (aFsorted$Used == aFsorted$Freq) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> sortedEdgeList

   V1 V2
12  e  f
13  f  g
14  g  h
10  d  g
5   a  b
4   b  c
7   c  d
11  d  h
2   a  e
51  b  e
8   c  g
3   a  f
6   b  f
9   c  h
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that. The warning is because of the comparison i made after the inner loops ends, where i compared `aFsorted$Used` with `aFsorted$Freq`. Since this result of comparison returned more than one row, the warning says it will only consider first element but surprisingly it compares all elements and even deletes all matching ones instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but it might be close.  It helps conceptually to keep the frequencies in the original data frame.

```
library("plyr")
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(letters[1:10], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(letters[1:10], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$freqV1 <- NA_integer_
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$freqV1[i] <- length(grep(pattern = df$V1[i], x = df$V1))
    }
df2 <- arrange(df, freqV1, V2) # you may want just arrange(df, freqV1)
```

which gives:

```
   V1 V2 freqV1
1   h  c      1
2   d  a      2
3   d  b      2
4   c  c      2
5   c  j      2
6   b  c      3
7   g  c      3
8   b  f      3
9   g  h      3
10  g  h      3
11  b  i      3
12  i  a      4
13  i  c      4
14  i  d      4
15  i  f      4
16  f  b      5
17  f  d      5
18  f  d      5
19  f  e      5
20  f  f      5
```

Comment: Hello Bryan. Thanks a lot for reading and assisting me with that code but that is not what i wanted. Ultimately i figured out after spending hours of scribbling on my notebook with a Sharpie :) Should i write my answer below as an answer? Would that give me any points or increase my rank?

Comment: I'm not sure if putting an answer down will earn any points.  Glad you figured out what you needed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your effort.